# Prevent multiple time form submit with enter key

Tags: jquery, enter

Below is my code

```
$('#myDIV').keydown(function (event) {
      var key=event.which || event.charCode;
      if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        importItem();
      }
});
```

When I press enter button multiple times the importItem() is getting called multiple times, How can i prevent this? I dont have submit fucntion here to use issubmitted kind of code.

Comment: you can try like this `var checker = true;
$('#myDIV').keydown(function(event) {
 var key = event.which || event.charCode;
 if (checker) {
  if (key == 13) // the enter key code
  {
   event.preventDefault();
   importItem();
   checker = false;
  }
 }

});`

Comment: it is not allowing me to use enter key second time for different form without refreshing the page

Comment: click event? you mean keydown event?

Comment: yes my bad like the sample in the comment above please check

Comment: checker will become true everytime I press enter key, this will not work i afraid.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Define a global flag
allowSubmit = true

// And in your custom submit event function
if allowSubmit
   $('#yourForm').submit() #Fire native submit function manually here
   allowSubmit = false
else
   return false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an event to prevent submissions after you verify its data, for example:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")

function importItem(e){
  // Your function...

  e.preventDefault() // Remove this
  console.log("Form submitted")

  form.removeEventListener("submit", importItem)
  form.addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault())
}

form.addEventListener("submit", importItem)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hold enter key">
</form>
```

Note: That first `e.preventDefault()` is used so the form can't redirect the page, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout() to delay and prevent multiple execution of code.

```
    var timeout = null;
    $('#myDIV').keydown(function (event) {
          var key=event.which || event.charCode;
          if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
          {
            event.preventDefault();
            if(timeout != null){
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
               importItem(); 
            }, 1000);
          }
    });
```

Comment: I pressed the enter key while form getting submitted with gap, then it got submitted multiple times again

Comment: So you want to finish the submission first before another enter key is allowed?

Comment: yes exactly, after a form got submitted then only i want enter key to fire again after press

Comment: can you post also your function `importItem()`